# View transitions in IOS [want to change background]

Tags: ios, xcode, background, transition

I'm having some doubts about transitions. The problem is that when i do the transition:

```
Register *register1 = [[Register alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.registerData = register1;
register1.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:register1 animated:YES];
```

The background of the transition appears in black like in this image:

[image]

How do you think guys i can solve this problem? I would like to have an image to replace this black background. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem once. In my case I inserted a `UIImageView` to the window of the MainWindow. Try the following code to see if this is the right place for you to insert the image:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

To use an image instead of a color:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 
    UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:background];
}
```

Comment: Peter! How did you do exactly to put and image as a background for the transitions? Maybe it would be better for me than a normal color! Thanks!

Comment: The color was just meant as a quick test to see whether this is the right place which works for you. I used the App-Template XCode gave me. This Template contains MainWindow.xib. Open this with Interface Builder and you'll see the Object "Window". Just drag an UIImageView in there, that's all i did... Bonne chance ;)